# Converting GML to Geodatabase format by using Productivity Suite software

Tags: convert, gml, format

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 version and would like to import MasterMap Integrated Transport Network from Digimap to ArcGIS, So I was following the steps:

1. Install Productivity Suites v 3.4.1
2. Import licence
3. Open OS MasterMap Data Converter.
   However, I got an error here about initialization error, which is shown below.

[image: Error]

What could the problem be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be an issue about licences, not about a GIS

Comment: Please transcribe the error message into the question. This permits it to be searched. The error message itself conflicts with your question body, that asserts 10.2 Desktop.